# Can one force XMLWriter to write elements in single quotes?

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

Here's my code:

```
var ptFirstName = tboxFirstName.Text;
writer.WriteAttributeString("first",ptFirstName);
```

note that ptFirstName will end up in double quotes even if I use

```
ptFirstName = ptFirstName.Replace("\"","'");
```

This does not work either since the writer will still force double quotes in my file as follows:

when in fact I need (don't ask me why - it's a long story...)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can set what character is used for quotes by setting the `XmlTextWriter.QuoteChar` property.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.quotechar.aspx for details.

But this means you have to create an XmlTextWriter object for this to work.

Comment: OK, that worked nicely! using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(targetFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
               
                {
                    writer.QuoteChar = '\'';
                    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

Comment: It's not correct because it only works on the to be deprecated `XmlTextWriter` extension and not the preferred `XmlWriter`

Comment: @yoshiya can you reference where it is detailed that using an `XmlWriter` property only works with `XmlTextWriter`?

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying now @Yoshiya  XmlTextWriter is the only class that has a QuoteChar property and XmlWriter.Create won't create an XmlTextWriter object; so you have to use XmlTextWriter explicitly.

Comment: @james You can use `XmlTextWriter` with `XmlDocument`.  This `XmlDocument` read/write overview touches on `QuoteChar`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/saving-and-writing-a-document and has an example of using `XmlTextWriter` and `XmlDocument`