# How can I change " " to ' ' in XmlDocument C#?

Tags: c#, excel, xml, linq, xmldocument

Currently, I have a code project to convert data from excel to xml and I am using XmlDocument to write xml file to run testcase in available software. But in that software when running xml it only receives.

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`

When I use CreateXmlDeclaration function of XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("'1.0", "'utf-8'", null);
```

My result -> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

I try modify it `<?xml version="'1.0'" encoding="'utf-8'"?>` and I get exception:

> an unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
> System.Xml.dll Wrong XML version information. The XML must match
> production "VersionNum ::= '1.' [0-9]+".

How can I use ' ' in CreateXmlDeclaration or use another API as an alternative to XmlDocument ?

Comment: It is supposed to be double quotes, why are you trying to force it into single?

Comment: In that case you have problems with all XML documents, because [the XML spec not only allows double quotes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126), all the examples actually use double quotes and even mixed quotes

Comment: You should consider using the new DOM `System.Xml.Linq` and `XDocument` instead in general.  Specifically you'd need to find the setting that controls the use of single quotes instead of double quotes when outputting the xml as text.  For `XmlDocument` that requires using an `XmlTextWriter` with `QuoteChar` set to single quote.  Note that will use single instead of double quotes for all attributes.

Comment: Hi @Crowcoder, because app of my firm using single quotes it is fixed and cannot be changed and it only accepts single quotes. I also don't want why. It's like it's by default.

Comment: @juharr, thank you, i consider use it.

Comment: A find/replace in Excel prior to export may work.

Comment: Hi @SolarMike, just <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> use single quotes and it not in the excel file, all data in excel use " "

Comment: 1) `<?xml version="'1.0'" encoding="'utf-8'"?>` is malformed.  According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-VersionInfo) it should be `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>` or `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but never `"'1.0'"` (with both types of quote at once).  Was that a typo in your question, or do you really want such malformed XML?

Comment: 2) Assuming you want `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`, do you also want the single quote char used for attributes also?  Or just for the XML declaration and nothing else?

Comment: More specifically, is this what you want?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNx7Dq

Comment: For example you could do this https://dotnetfiddle.net/0HaYFA

Comment: Thank you everyone, I undertood and resolved a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here:

1. There is no need to manually add an XML Declaration to an [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument) by calling [`CreateXmlDeclaration()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createxmldeclaration).  The XML Declaration will be written automatically using the current encoding when you call one of the overloads of [`XmlDocument.Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save).  It will not be written when you inspect the value of [`OuterXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml) or call [`XmlDocument.WriteTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.writeto).
2. When writing XML using [`XmlTextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter) you may control the quote character by setting [`XmlTextWriter.QuoteChar = '\''`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.quotechar)<sup>[1]</sup>.

   Note that this property controls both the quote character used in the XML declaration, and the quote character used for attribute values.

   Note also that, while `XmlTextWriter` has been deprecated in favor of calling [`XmlWriter.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create?view=net-6.0), there does not appear to be a way to set the quote character using [`XmlWriterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=net-6.0).

Thus, if you want to use a single quote character for both the XML declaration and attribute values, you can introduce the following extension method:

```
public static partial class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string GetOuterXml(this XmlDocument doc, bool indent = true, char quoteChar = '"')
    {
        if (doc == null)
            return null;
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = indent ? Formatting.Indented : Formatting.None, QuoteChar = quoteChar })
            {
                doc.Save(xmlWriter);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public sealed class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
{
    // From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584394/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583299/xmlwriter-encoding-utf-8-using-stringwriter-in-c-sharp
    public StringWriterWithEncoding() : this(Encoding.UTF8) { }
    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding) => this.Encoding = encoding;
    public override Encoding Encoding { get; }
}
```

And, for the XML `<foo Name="hello"><bar Id="101">var value</bar></foo>`, the method
`doc.GetOuterXml(quoteChar : '\'')` will generate:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<foo Name='hello'>
  <bar Id='101'>var value</bar>
</foo>
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pU31eA).

Notice that the single quote character is used for both the XML declaration and attribute values.  Your question is unclear, but if you need a single quote for the XML Declaration **only** and double quotes otherwise, you will need to subclass `XmlTextWriter` like so:

```
public static partial class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string GetOuterXml(this XmlDocument doc, bool indent = true)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            return null;
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = new CustomQuoteCharXmlTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = indent ? Formatting.Indented : Formatting.None })
            {
                doc.Save(xmlWriter);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomQuoteCharXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public CustomQuoteCharXmlTextWriter(Stream w, Encoding encoding) : base(w, encoding) => QuoteChar = '\'';
    public CustomQuoteCharXmlTextWriter(String filename, Encoding encoding) : base(filename, encoding) => QuoteChar = '\'';
    public CustomQuoteCharXmlTextWriter(TextWriter w) : base(w) => QuoteChar = '\'';
    
    public override void WriteStartDocument() 
    {
        base.WriteStartDocument();
        QuoteChar = '"';
    }
}
```

And now `doc.GetOuterXml()` will return:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<foo Name="hello">
  <bar Id="101">var value</bar>
</foo>
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNx7Dq).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15457031) by [Peter Ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5620/peter-ritchie) to *[Can one force XMLWriter to write elements in single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15457011/3744182)*